# fixed header stay on top of the page after scolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a prototype for a fix header like you would see in [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com)

So if you scroll down the page to certain amount of pixels, the header will become fixed and stay at the top of the browser.

This is what I have so far -

```js
var wrap = $("#wrap");

wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {
    
  if (this.scrollTop > 120) {
    wrap.addClass("fix-header");
  } else {
    wrap.removeClass("fix-header");
  }
  
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height:480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 20px;
  
}

.header p {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 90px;
  font: 300 30px Oswald;
  
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: grey;
}

.fix-header .header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap" class="container">
  
  <div class="header">
    <p>This is the Header</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwbpxX

So here is the problem, this fixed header would only work with `overflow: auto` for `.container`. And I have to set the height of `.container` smaller than it actually contains.

I also notice if we scroll the page and the fixed header is extending its width to the scroll bar as the following image shows.
[image]

How do I -

1. make the fixed header work without having a smaller height container.
2. have the fixed header not extending over the scroll bar.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include relevant code **directly inside your question**.  Links can become outdated and obsolete, which will render your question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your stuff on the `body` not on the `#wrap` so you won't have to change the `overflow` or the height of the `.container`.